# Changing the order of the summation $\sum_{i\in I_2} \sum_{j\in I_2} a_{ij}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading the book: "Deimling Nonlinear Analysis" and I'm blocked on a proof, at page 27, when proving Jordan's separation theorem.

At some point, we want to show that two sets, let's say $I_1$ and $I_2$, have the same cardinality, by looking at the sums indexed by the elements of these two sets.
If both sets have the same cardinality the proof is pretty straightforward.

We know in fact that $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $$ \begin{cases} 1 = \sum_{j\in I_1} a_{ij} \ \text{ for every } i \in I_2\\
1 = \sum_{i\in I_2} a_{ij} \ \text{ for every } j \in I_1\\\end{cases} $$

so, putting together the two equations
$$\#I_2 = \sum_{i\in I_2} \sum_{j\in I_1} a_{ij} = \sum_{i\in I_1}\sum_{j\in I_2} a_{ij} = \#I_1 $$

the book now states that this implies the two sets have the same cardinality... even in the infinite case! And this gives me a lot of doubts because in this situation I have to deal with a series that diverges to infinity.

I tried to prove assume, by contradiction, that one set has finite cardinality and the other not, but even if one summation is finite, I have to rearrange infinite terms to get anything useful, which isn't justified I guess. As follows:
If $I_2 = \mathbb{N}$ and $I_1= \{1,...,N_0\}$
$$1 = \sum_{j=1}^{N_0} a_{ij}\Rightarrow\\
\Rightarrow \lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=1}^{N_0} a_{ij} = \lim_{k\to\infty}k\\
\Rightarrow \lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{N_0}\sum_{i=1}^k a_{ij} = \infty\\
\Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^{N_0}\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^k a_{ij} = \infty\\
\Rightarrow\sum_{j=1}^{N_0} \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_{ij} = \infty\\\\
\Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^{N_0} 1 = \infty\\
\Rightarrow N_0 = \infty
$$
And this should be a contradiction. **BUT** this proof is sketchy *at best*.

Below you can find a screenshot of the proof.
Can anyone please help me?

[image]

Comment: Your equation is trivial. Something is wrong with your formulas. Anyway, either verify each equality one by one, or verify all of them by cases.

Comment: Yes sorry I messed up the indexes. Now it's correct I think. Regarding the second part of your comment, I thought that assuming no one of them to be finite could result in an even grater source of problems so I avoided it. If you could sketch an outline of the proof I would try it though

Comment: Is it known that $a_{ij}$'s all non-negative, or at least only finitely many of them are negative? In that case, the equality follows from Fubini–Tonelli theorem. Otherwise, the equality need not hold true as we see in the example $$a_{ij}=\begin{cases} 1, & i = j \\ -1, & i = j+1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}, \qquad i, j = 0, 1, 2, \ldots $$ For this $(a_{ij})$, we get $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_{ij}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\mathbf{1}[i=0]=1\quad\neq\quad 0=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_{ij}. $$

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you very much for the counterexample. I think that the best you can say about the $a_{ij}$ is that, from the equations in the curly braces, that in each sum $\sum_{j\in I_1} a_{ij}$ only finitely many are different than zero, for every $i\in I_2$

Comment: @SangchulLee  Sorry I see only now that your example doesn't verify the hypothesis $\begin{cases} 1 = \sum_{j\in I_1} a_{ij} \ \text{ for every } i \in I_2\\
1 = \sum_{i\in I_2} a_{ij} \ \text{ for every } j \in I_1\\\end{cases}$

Comment: A sketch of the definition of d might be illuminating. Can it take negative values for example?

Comment: Oh right, $d(f,\Omega,y)$ is the topological degree of $f$ (or Brouwer degree). The full definition is a bit cumbersome, for the regular case (but it's not this case) it's just the sum $ \sum_{x\in f^{-1}(y)} \operatorname{sgn} \det f'(x)$ But I don't really think it can be useful. It can be negative, as stated in $a_{ij}\in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If one of $I_1$ or $I_2$ is finite, then the equality

$$ \sum_{i\in I_1} \sum_{j \in I_2} a_{ij} = \sum_{j \in I_2} \sum_{i\in I_1} a_{ij} $$

holds whenever $\sum_{i\in I_1} a_{ij}$ converges for all $j$ and $\sum_{j \in I_2} a_{ij}$ converges for all $i$, regardless of the value of the sums. (Since either $I_1$ or $I_2$ is assumed to be finite, at least one of these two conditions is trivial.)

This essentially follows from (repeated application of) the linearity of infinite summation:

> **Fact.** If $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i$ converges, then $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (a_i + b_i)$ also converges and
>
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (a_i + b_i). $$

**2.** The above discussion leaves the verification of OP's equality in only one case, when both $I_1$ and $I_2$ are infinite. In this case, the equality between the double sums does not always hold in the general case. However, in OP's case,

$$ \sum_{i\in I_1} \sum_{j \in I_2} a_{ij} = \sum_{i\in I_1} 1 = \# I_1 = \infty $$

and

$$ \sum_{j \in I_2} \sum_{i\in I_1} a_{ij} = \sum_{j \in I_2} 1 = \# I_2 = \infty, $$

hence they are equal.

So, in the case both $I_1$ and $I_2$ are infinite, their "cardinality"<sup>1)</sup> are already the same and we simply verified the two double sums also respect this equality as well. This means that the only non-trivial argument takes place when at least one of $I_1$ or $I_2$ is finite.

---

<sup>1) This is not the same notion of cardinality used in set theory, in which several inequivalent infinite cardinals exist.</sup>